Find a linear transformation $w$ which maps the upper half plane onto the unit disk so that $w(2i)=0$ and $w’(2i)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$
I do not know how to control the derivative at $2i$. I know that conformal maps from $\mathbb{H}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ takes the form $e^{i\theta}\frac{z-\beta}{z-\bar\beta}$. In this case then $\beta$ must be $2i$. Hence I get $e^{i\theta}\frac{z-2i}{z+2i}$. But the trouble is this map always has derivative $e^{i\theta}\frac{1}{4i}$ at $2i$, which is not even the same modulus as $-\frac{\pi}{2}$. What am I missing?

It seems that the exercise is wrong.
